# how vertically center link in div

Tags: html, css

The search now link is stuck aligned to the top of the div.  How do I make this link centered vertically in the div?

```css
.advanced-button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: #f4c23d;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.advanced-button a {
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #222222;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.advanced-button i {
  float: right;
  width: 40px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f0b20e;
}
```

```html
<div class="advanced-button">
  <a href="#">Search Now<i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to set the line height on the link to match the height of the div:

```css
.advanced-button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: #f4c23d;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.advanced-button a {
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #222222;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height:55px;
}
.advanced-button i {
  float: right;
  width: 40px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f0b20e;
}
```

```html
<div class="advanced-button">
  <a href="#">Search Now<i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Works only for single line. Multi-line text will look bad

Comment: @Justinas Yes, however this particular case is a single line of text

Answer (score 1):

Just add `line-height: 55px;` to the link.

```css
.advanced-button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: #f4c23d;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.advanced-button a {
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #222222;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 55px;
}
.advanced-button i {
  float: right;
  width: 40px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f0b20e;
}
```

```html
<div class="advanced-button">
  <a href="#">Search Now<i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
</div>
```